# Zend Framework - How to manage subscription plan privileges

Tags: rest, zend-framework, subscription

I'm developing a REST API using Zend Framework 1.12.3.

I have to implement subscriptions for different types of plans (i.e. Basic and Premium), each plan having different privileges (e.g. Premium may offer instant, daily and weekly SMS notifications, while Basic may offer only weekly SMS notifications).

Also, there may be custom plans only for certain clients.

I've added a column in the users table called `subscription`, but what I cannot figure out is where to save the privileges for each subscription plan.

Should I save these privileges directly into the DB (i.e. create a table called `subscriptions`, and another one called `subscriptions_privileges` having as columns `subscription_id`, `privilege_name` and `privilege_value`), or would it be better if I save them into the config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note: Actually this question is not linked with Zend Framework, it is system architecture question.

**Short answer:**

- it is much more easy to hardcode your subscription plans in your source code configuration files;
- it is much more flexible to store this data in database (you can create some administration panel to allow managers to manage them, track history of plan changes, use these data in analytical SQL queries). Theoretically you can deal with all this stuff through reading and writing to your config files, but databases are just the exact tool for these tasks.

P.S.: You can add separate layer of abstartion in your application. Use model objects for your subscriptions which can be populated either from database or from your hard-coded config files using different adapters.